# Xubuntu issue - where are the default desktop icons disapeared?

Tags: icons

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 LTS and for some reason the default desktop icons (Trash, File System, and Home) have disappeared? Anyone have any ideas where they went and how to get them back?

Comment: Not only that it seems I can not place ANY icons on the desktop? What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say what's the reason for disappearing icons. 
 But If you want them back here is 
what you do :-

1. Download Ubuntu-Tweak from [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/173353757/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1%7Etrusty2_all.deb)
2. Install by double clicking.
3. Open it from the Dash.
4. Goto Tweaks button(3rd from top left) -> Desktop -> Desktop icons.
5. Now enable desktop icons and choose the icons you want to show on the desktop.

**OR** 
use the following commands.

**$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-visible true

$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop computer-icon-visible true

$ gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible true**

Comment: I downloaded and installed Ubuntu-Tweak. The installation went well, however..... I can't seem to find it now, so I can't run it. Where should I look for it? Remember I'm running xUbuntu. Thanks for your time. JamesKB

Comment: I found Ubuntu Tweak, however when I go to the Tweaks button the only option under Desktop there is NO option for Desktop  Icons, only Wallpaper????

Comment: I tried the commands you suggested. Did not work. The 2d and 3d one returned error message: No such key: 'computer-icon-visible' and No such key: 'trash-icon-visible'  Any more suggestions???